# How do I use constructer for a class with a class as a field in C# Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am just getting started with Entity Framework Core within C#, and I'm trying to set up a class structure where one class has a field that is another class. I have found that, when the classes do not have constructors, the code runs fine. However, when I introduce a constructor as follows:

```
    public class InterestEF
    {
        public InterestEF(string id, int numTimesInterestSelected, AdminEditEF lastEdit, ICollection<AdminEditEF> allEdits)
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.numTimesInterestSelected = numTimesInterestSelected;
            this.lastEdit = lastEdit;
            this.allEdits = allEdits;
        }

        [Key]
        public string id { get; set; }
        public int numTimesInterestSelected { get; set; }
        public AdminEditEF lastEdit { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<AdminEditEF> allEdits { get; set; }
    }

    public class AdminEditEF
    {
        public AdminEditEF(string id, string adminIdEditedBy, DateTime dateEdited, string changesMade, string reasonsForChanges, string idOfEditedEntity, EntityTypeEdited entityTypeEdited)
        {
            this.id = id;
            AdminIdEditedBy = adminIdEditedBy;
            this.dateEdited = dateEdited;
            this.changesMade = changesMade;
            this.reasonsForChanges = reasonsForChanges;
            this.idOfEditedEntity = idOfEditedEntity;
            this.entityTypeEdited = entityTypeEdited;
        }

        [Key]
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string AdminIdEditedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime dateEdited { get; set; }
        public string changesMade { get; set; }
        public string reasonsForChanges { get; set; }
        public string idOfEditedEntity { get; set; }
        public EntityTypeEdited entityTypeEdited { get; set; }
    }

    public class MySQLEFContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<AdminEditEF> AdminEdits { get; set; }

        public DbSet<InterestEF> interests { get; set; }

        public MySQLEFContext(DbContextOptions<MySQLEFContext> options): base(options) { }

    }
```

I get the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'No suitable constructor found for entity type 'InterestEF'. The following constructors had parameters that could not be bound to properties of the entity type: cannot bind 'lastEdit' in 'InterestEF(string id, int numTimesInterestSelected, AdminEdit lastEdit)'.'
```

Basically, I'm just wondering if it's possible to have a class that has classes as fields that also has a set of constructors with parameters I can call elsewhere within code?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you so much for reading!

Comment: You can just add another parameterless constructor too.

Comment: Would it be possible to add a constructor with parameters, though? I want to be able to have a set of constructors that take different parameters depending on what I want to do with the class. I appreciate your answering so quickly, too! Thank you!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/constructors Shortly, you could have as many constructors as you wish for your own needs, but at least one, even private to be used by EF Core when materializing entity returning queries.

Comment: oh! that makes sense! thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/constructors):

> - EF Core cannot set navigation properties (such as Blog or Posts above) using a constructor.

So you would need a constructor that looks like this:

```
public InterestEF(string id, int numTimesInterestSelected)
{
    this.id = id;
    this.numTimesInterestSelected = numTimesInterestSelected;
}
```

Or a parameterless one:

```
public InterestEF()
{
}
```